# Javascript in HTML questions - delaying and updating

Tags: javascript, html

Though an experienced programmer, I'm a notice to using HTML/Javascript. I've posted my code below. What I'd like to do and haven't been able to is:

- Delay execution of the `refreshmap()` (e.g. delay of 500 ms). I put in the `setTimeout` function but it doesn't seem to be delaying anything at all, even with large values.
- Get the correct output. Currently, `distance` and `duration` are updated in the printed result after each iteration of the for-loop, but the latitude/longitude data never is (see attached output).

Html Section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Driving Distances and Times dataset creator</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: red;white-space:pre-wrap;"> 

<form action="#" onsubmit="setRequest(); return false;" style="white-space:normal;">
<p>
Origin:
<input type="text" name="address1" value="Chicago" />
</p>
<p>
Latitude 1:
<input type="number" name="beginLat" value="35" />
Longitude 1:
<input type="number" name="beginLong" value="-80" />
</p>
<p>
Latitude 2:
<input type="number" name="endLat" value="40" />
Longitude 2:
<input type="number" name="endLong" value="-90" />
</p>
<p>
Divisions per side:
<input type="number" name="divisions" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
</form>
<p id="results"></p>
<div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Javascript definition:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var myOptions = {zoom:7,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {origin: 'Chicago', destination: 'New York', travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING};
```

Get data from HTML form:

```
function setRequest(msg) {
    var address1 = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
    var lat1 = document.forms[0].elements[1].value;
    var long1 = document.forms[0].elements[2].value;
    var lat2 = document.forms[0].elements[3].value;
    var long2 = document.forms[0].elements[4].value;
    var ndiv = document.forms[0].elements[5].value;

    request.origin = address1;
    var k = 0;

    if (lat1>lat2) {
        var temp = lat2;
        lat2 = lat1;
        lat1 = temp;
    }


    if (long1>long2) {
        var temp = long2;
        long2 = long1;
        long1 = temp;
    }

    if (ndiv < 1) {
        ndiv = 1;
    }

    dlat = (lat2-lat1)/ndiv;
    dlong = (long2-long1)/ndiv;

    initial = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < ndiv; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < ndiv; j++) { 
            latitude = parseFloat(lat1) + dlat*0.5 + dlat*i;
            longitude = parseFloat(long1) + dlong*0.5 + dlong*j;
            request.destination = "" + latitude + "°, " + longitude + "°";
            setTimeout(refreshmap(),500);
        }
    }
};
```

Solve for travel time and display:

```
function refreshmap() {
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

        if (initial == 0) {
            var lat1 = latitude - 0.5*dlat;
            var lat2 = latitude + 0.5*dlat;
            var long1 = longitude - 0.5*dlong;
            var long2 = longitude + 0.5*dlong;
            var outstring = "" + latitude + ", " + longitude + ", " +     response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + ", " + response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value     + ", " + lat1 + ", " + long1 + ", " + lat2 + ", " + long2;

            document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(outstring +     String.fromCharCode(13,10)));

        }

        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

    }
});
};

var initial = 1;
var lat,long,dlat,dlong = 0;
refreshmap();
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Output:

```
39.375, -88.75, 1184906, 39431, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 925474, 31504, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 834733, 27469, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 838895, 28560, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 1021536, 35325, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 776387, 26518, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 665551, 22838, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 627540, 21552, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 844986, 29534, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
39.375, -88.75, 663110, 21951, 38.75, -87.5, 40, -90
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful tips!

After getting stuck here, I've tried an alternative of making the javascript only look up one location, fed to it via url parameters set in a python script. That way, I know the output will be unique and I can delay all I want. I got stuck this way in getting the reading the output from updated page. Even using ghost.py and `<div>` tags, I couldn't get the updated info out. Is this still a better route to pursue? I wanted to abide by the TOS by displaying the map everytime.

Comment: `setTimeout(refreshmap(),500);` should be            `setTimeout(refreshmap,500);` - you're _passing_ the function as a parameter, not calling it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Interesting. That definitely delays the first iteration, but none of the subsequent. And now, all the output is homogenous, not even varied in distance/duration (as if it's only looking up that single location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what's going on is that it's delaying the call, and then using the last set of latitude and longitude. That's because you're using global variables, and the variables are changing before `refreshMap` actually gets called.

What you should do is change the `setTimeout(refreshmap(), 500)` line to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    refreshmap(latitude, longitude);
}, 500);
```

and then change your `refreshmap` function to something like:

```
function refreshmap(latitude, longitude){...}
```

You might have to include other variables, as well.

Comment: Good point about using parameters rather than global variables - that totally fixes the unique output issue! It still doesn't delay between each step though.

Comment: Okay, so what you want is 500 ms between each run, correct? Then you need your `refreshmap` function to call itself with a timeout, after doing whatever it needs to do to update the latitude/longitude. The issue is that all of your timeouts are being set up right in a row, with 500 ms delays FROM SETUP, not from each other. Does that make sense? It'll be helpful to use recursion, basically.

Comment: I apologize: using parameters and `setTimeout(refreshmap(latitude,longitude),500)` fixes the output unique-ness, but not the delay - to be expected. But, using `setTimeout(function() {refreshmap(latitude, longitude);},500);` seems to fix neither.

Comment: So if I remake `refreshmap(latitude,longitude)` into a recursive structure and put the `setTimeout(function...)` as the initial/external call and internal call, it would have the delays sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(refreshmap(),500);
```

Here you are calling the function directly, and passing the result of the call to `setTimeout()`. Instead, you need to *pass the function* to setTimeout. Like this:

```
setTimeout(refreshmap, 500);
```

This can be a bit alien to someone who is not familiar with functional languages.

You can check out the [`setTimeout()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) for further clarification.

Comment: See above response. This definitely delays the first call (progress!), but not any subsequent ones in the for-loop.